# Proper way of declaring/evaling multiple ActiveRecord models into the main namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, metaprogramming

Imagine an array of strings `["User","Article","Image"]`, what's the best way of evaluating their class declarations into the current scope? I'm imagining something like:

```
array.each do |element|
  instance_eval<<EOF
    class #{element} < ActiveRecord::Base
    end
EOF
end
```

Is this the proper way of doing it?

Comment: So which option did you go with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
array.each do |element|
  Object.const_set(element, Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base))
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bounty notice and couldn't award it. I started a new bounty, and in about 23 hours I will award it to you.

Comment: Oh well, I didn't expect you to go back and do that!  I just wanted to make sure the answer was helpful - in retrospect, it's kind of lacking in explanation.

Answer (score 3):

what about

```
%w(User Article Image).each do |klass|
  create_class(klass, ActiveRecord::Base) do
    # ...whatever
  end
end
```

Comment: Hm, what's that `create_class`? Seems not to be available in global scope.

Comment: Indeed. It's not nice of him to use code that isn't referenced.